# The nitrogen cycle

Tags: biochemistry

As I understand it, bacteria absorb nitrogen from the air, and deposit nitrates in the soil. These are absorbed by plants which use them to build complex molecules such as proteins. This enters the food chain. Eventually an organism dies and decays, and nitrogen is released into the atmosphere again.  This is called the nitrogen cycle.

Am I correct so far?

My question: what percentage of atmospheric nitrogen is involved in the cycle per year?

Background to the question: On another forum I was involved in discussing the old statement that every breath we take contains a molecule of Caesar's dying breath. We raised the point about molecules being ripped apart, and created by biological processes. One person said that the nitrogen cycle is so slow that virtually all the nitrogen molecules from Caesar's time still exist unchanged. That statement is one I found surprising.  Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. This is a question and answer site, not a personal  proof-reading site as you will see if you finish reading the [Tour]. Please do so. We work on the basis of one question per post. What is your question? Initially it appears to be about the percentage of atmospheric nitrogen fixed each year — a consideration that is hardly at the forefront of modern biology, but must be of interest to somebody. However then it seems to morph into astrophysics, in relation to the conservation of nitrogen on earth, together with the speed of the cycle — whatever that may mean.

Comment: I thought my question is perfectly clear: "what percentage of atmospheric nitrogen is involved in the cycle per year?"  The rest is merely stating the reason why I'm asking the question.   I don't see what proofreading has to do with it, nor astrophysics.

Comment: Proof-reading: "Am I correct so far". Astrophysics: "all the nitrogen molecules from Caesar's time still exist unchanged" suggested loss from the earth's atmosphere.

Comment: Not proofreading. It's just establishing if I've understood the basic premise correctly.  You can ignore that line if you wish. As for astrophysics, it's not about losing from Earth's atmosphere,  it's about chemical reactions destroying molecules, and creating different molecules.  I thought I made that clear.

Comment: OK, OK. You could have found the answer yourself — simple queries, first page of answers — but I've done it for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Mass of Nitrogen in Atmosphere**

ca. 4 x 10<sup>18</sup>kg (Wikipedia page on [“Atmosphere of Earth”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth))

**Nitrogen fixed by natural, nonagricultural organisms per annum**

ca. 2 x 10<sup>11</sup>kg ([“Global Nitrogen: Cycling out of Control”](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1247398/))

**Atmospheric nitrogen fixed per annum**

**ca. 0.5 x 10<sup>–5</sup> %**

**Conclusion**

If we are still breathing molecules of Caesar’s dying breath, they will be quite diluted.

Comment: I wasn't expecting us to "run out" of nitrogen, since any nitrogen fixed by bacteria will eventually be released back. Aside from that, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Pete — Seemed a bit bald without a comment. Perhaps I’ll try a different tack. The actual turnover time is a more difficult question. It may have been 50 years or for the average Roman emperor to return to the earth, but much less for the rats in the streets.

Comment: +1 Nice article (second link). I did not know that, like, no clue whatsoever. So Thanks for that.

Comment: Suggestion: The best practice is to write numbers in scientific notation in terms of the base unit kg, not the unprefixed unit g. This helps when doing calculations, e.g. kg × m/s^2 = N (newton). So, 4×10^21 g = 4×10^18 kg.

Comment: @Nayuki — You may well be right, but I am unaware of that practice. Can you provide a link documenting it? If you are correct I will change it.

Comment: The dying breath part needs fleshing.  Tidal volume = 500 mL /(15 mol/L at 37C) = 1/30 mol air = 38 mmol N2 = 2.9E+22 molecules with negligible fixation in 2000 years (0.01%).  Atmosphere has (4E21g/28 g/mol)*6E23/mol = 8.6E43.  New breath gets (2.9E+22/8.6E+43)*2.9E+22 = 10 molecules.  (Unless the old tyrant was poked so full of holes that the last breath was more like a faint gurgle, that is...  more pleasant to run this math for the Sermon on the Mount, no?)

Comment: @David I looked through the [SI Brochure](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure) and it has surprisingly little to say about style. As far as I can tell, all examples in the document use kg, such as on page 150, "m_n = 1.674 927 471 (21) × 10^−27 kg".

Comment: @David Using g instead of kg is factually and numerically correct, but it makes advanced usages harder. Look at the Wikipedia page for Earth or proton, and you'll see their masses stated in scientific notation kilograms. Secondly, other units are "coherently derived" from base units, meaning that you multiply base units together with a trivial scale factor of 1. For example, 1 newton = 1 kilogram × metre / second^2 = 1000 g × m/s^2. When doing calculations, it's tremendously helpful when all quantities are stated in base units - and that means using the kilogram.

Comment: @David It's true that the other 6 base units have no prefix (metre, second, etc.) and behave nicely. But for historical reasons, the community reneged on the gram and then decided to base everything else on the kilogram - the newton, pascal, joule, volt, etc. So now we're stuck with a coherent system having a base unit that has a prefix, but does not take double prefixes (e.g. μkg → mg) and thus also behaves as though gram is the base unit for the purpose of prefixing.

Comment: @Nayuki — OK. Thanks. We biochemists tend to think small, so that the question seldom arises. Will fix when I have a mo.